# Whats the highest voltage dc motor that my mosfet can control?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, dc-motor

I am using a IRF520N Logic level mosfet to control a dc motor with my Arduiono Uno. What types of DC Motors (i.e 20-24V) can I use without damaging the mosfet?

Datasheet: http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/68160/IRF/IRF520N.html

Comment: Brushless, brushed, realistically most types of DC motor.

Answer (score 1):

V<sub>(BR)DSS</sub> (Drain-to-Source Breakdown Voltage) says 100V.

Comment: Correct but OP seems to be asking about types of DC motors in the 20-24V range rather than the IRF520 voltage- most confusing and IMHO its a shopping question.

Comment: @JImDearden: *shrug* I just went by what the title says.

Comment: Thank you all. I just wanted to know if I used a 20-24V Dc Motor if my Mosfet will not be damaged with giving that I will need to connect it in series to the arduino pin and 24v power supply. According to the datasheet i can add up to a 100V power supply? And that most current that will come out of the drain is 9.7A?

Comment: Fair comment  - its very misleading

Comment: @AlexLogorz "And that most current that will come out of the drain is 9.7A" doesn't make much sense. When using a fixed-voltage supply, the current flowing is a product of resistance or load, depending on which model you prefer. For example, a 50V 100W motor will (ignoring transients) pull 2A when supplied by a 50V fixed-voltage supply, because P=IV and thus I=P/V. Similarly, a circuit with a resistance of 25 ohms will pull 2A when supplied with a constant 50V, because V=IR and thus I=V/R.

Comment: @AlexLogorz The *Ids* current rating of the transistor is the maximum current that you can source through the transistor's drain-source junction without damaging it. You need to keep your current below this value. It won't magically limit the current for you.

Comment: @Polynomial Thank you for that detailed explanation.